# I got a message "using Plots" in Julia and I do no how to resolve it

Tags: windows, installation, ffmpeg, julia, julia-plots

I am a new in Julia and after adding the Plots package I tried to use Plots and I got this Error message:

```
julia> using Plots
[ Info: Precompiling Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80]
ERROR: LoadError: InitError: could not load library "C:\Users\niri.julia\artifacts\7350a6401f1c0d38cc3518193083bc4f83adfe99\bin\avcodec-58.dll"
The specified module could not be found.
Stacktrace:

ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile FFMPEG [c87230d0-a227-11e9-1b43-d7ebe4e7570a] to C:\Users\niri.julia\compiled\v1.5\FFMPEG\TGvga_Ik59J.ji.

ERROR: Failed to precompile Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80] to
```

can someone help me to resolve the problem

Comment: I think you need to specify what OS you are on, and your julia version

Comment: After you get this error, install the package [`DependencyWalker.jl`](https://github.com/giordano/DependencyWalker.jl) with `]add DependencyWalker` and then run `using DependencyWalker; Library(raw"C:\Users\niri.julia\artifacts\7350a6401f1c0d38cc3518193083bc4f83adfe99\bin\avcodec-58.dll")`.  This should tell you what library is missing.

Comment: Thank you, I did it and I got this response (✗ C:\Users\niri.julia\artifacts\7350a6401f1c0d38cc3518193083bc4f83adfe99\bin\avcodec-58.dll (NOT FOUND))

Comment: As pointed out below, the path you showed in the question looks wrong, it should probably be `C:\Users\niri\.julia\artifacts\7350a6401f1c0d38cc3518193083bc4f83adfe99\bin\avcodec-58.dll`?  The argument to the `Library` function should be whatever you seen in the terminal

Answer (score 2):

Try to install `FFMPEG`, rebuild this and `Plots` as well

```
using Pkg
pkg"add FFMPEG"
pkg"build FFMPEG"
pkg"build Plots"
```

There is good chance it will work.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to help. `FFMPEG.jl` doesn't need to be built, my guess is that the operating system doesn't provide all needed libraries, I've seen that on servers

Comment: Don't artifacts get downloaded during the build step of Julia package life cycle?  Of course if there is problem with OS libraries that could be a separate story.

Comment: No, they're installed at `add` time

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I did rebuild the FFMPEG and Plots but still I get the same Error. What is the latest version of Julia? mine is 1.5.1 . I was wondering the problem may be resolved in the latest version. I have Windows 10 Enterprise N

Comment: It works for me on the same config. Your console is showing some strange path: `C:\Users\niri.julia` I guess it should be `C:\Users\niri\.julia`. Perhaps something bad happened to your Julia conf? I would try to delete `C:\Users\niri\.julia`. and reinstall packages.